# Is it possible to stop including a php file?

Tags: php, include

Is it possible to stop the inclusion of a file in the middle of a file?

For example, one file would contain:

```
include('home.php');
```

and in `home.php`, it would try to cancel the inclusion at some point:

```
break; // I tried it doesn't work
echo "this will not be output
```

I'm not talking about an `exit`, which stops everything, even the root file. I just want the current file to be exited from.

Comment: It's very hard to understand what you're trying to do here. Please give an example, or a better explanation of what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

In place of [`break`](http://php.net/break), use [`return`](http://php.net/return):

> #### [`return`](http://php.net/return)
>
> If called from the global scope, then execution of the current script file is ended. If the current script file was `include()`ed or `require()`ed, then control is passed back to the calling file.

Comment: I take it that if the script was run without being called by `include()` that it would still cease execution then?

Comment: @GigaWatt:  That's what the documentation says.

Comment: wow super nice. I wonder why I never learned that earlier. Feels like few people know this.

Answer (score 5):

No. When you include or require. This file gets loaded and parsed entirely. It does not mean that the code in it is executed, but it is *loaded entirely*.

If you want to have a different flow of execution of this code, then you would need to use some of the control structures.

http://php.net/manual/en/language.control-structures.php

Comment: Cheers, for the down vote, but the original question is asking about "including a PHP file", which my answer is 100% correct on. You cannot stop the inclusion of a file. If he wanted to ask about preventing the execution, I would of thought he would of said that.

Comment: Just to add to this answer, if you put a return in your included file and have syntax error after the return it will still get killed by a fatal error.

Answer (score 4):

What you can do is set a flag in the "parent" script that the included script looks for.  If it's set, it'll halt execution early, otherwise it'll continue as normal.

Example:

*main.php*

```
<?php
$_GLOBAL['is_included'] = true;
include('somefile.php');
// More stuff here
?>
```

*somefile.php*

```
<?php
// Does some stuff

// Stops here if being include()'d by another script
if ( isset($_GLOBAL['is_included']) ) { return; }

// Do some more stuff if not include()'d
?>
```